# How to Convert Ragged Tensor to Tensor in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, tensor

I have a ragged tensor, and upon trying to create a model, and use model.fit(), I get an error:
`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_tensor.RaggedTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("Cast_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32), row_splits=Tensor("RaggedFromVariant_1/RaggedTensorFromVariant:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.`

Is this an issue with the shape of my data? Perhaps the data altogether? Maybe I need to use a sparse or dense tensor instead? Here is my full traceback error:

[image: Full Traceback]

As well as my data: [image: XTrain dataset]

Comment: Can you please create a minimal example tha reproduces the error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Every `RaggedTensor` has an associated `to_tensor()` method, call that. Check your input data transformations, that is where the RaggedTensor is getting created. Some ops return `RaggedTensor`.

Comment: Don't forget to set `default_value=` - or is it not necessary?